# How do I speed up pattern recognition in perl

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, fasta

This is the program as it stands right now, it takes in a .fasta file (a file containing genetic code), creates a hash table with the data and prints it, however, it is quite slow.  It splits a string an compares it against all other letters in the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $total = $#ARGV + 1;
my $row;
my $compare;
my %hash;
my $unique = 0;
open( my $f1, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[0] ) or die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]' $!\n";

my $discard = <$f1>;
while ( $row = <$f1> ) {
    chomp $row;
    $compare .= $row;
}
my $size = length($compare);
close $f1;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $size - 6; $i++ ) {
    my $vs = ( substr( $compare, $i, 5 ) );
    for ( my $j = 0; $j < $size - 6; $j++ ) {
        foreach my $value ( substr( $compare, $j, 5 ) ) {
            if ( $value eq $vs ) {
                if ( exists $hash{$value} ) {
                    $hash{$value} += 1;
                } else {
                    $hash{$value} = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach my $val ( values %hash ) {
    if ( $val == 1 ) {
        $unique++;
    }
}

my $OUTFILE;
open $OUTFILE, ">output.txt" or die "Error opening output.txt: $!\n";
print {$OUTFILE} "Number of unique keys: " . $unique . "\n";
print {$OUTFILE} Dumper( \%hash );
close $OUTFILE;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you got a sample input file? Have you tried printing out timing statements to work out what is taking up the time?

Comment: Can you also explain exactly what you are trying to do in the script? It is difficult to optimise when you aren't sure what the script is actually supposed to do! Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't have to check if a hash value exists before incrementing it.  `$foo{bar}++` will set a previously-undefined key to `1` without generating a warning.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, the .fasta file has a 1 line header, followed by rows of data separated by \n.  You can download .fasta files here http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blastcgihelp.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear from the description what is wanted from this script, but if you're looking for matching sets of 5 characters, you don't actually need to do any string matching: you can just run through the whole sequence and keep a tally of how many times each 5-letter sequence occurs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str; # store the sequence here
my %hash;
# slurp in the whole file
open(IN, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $ARGV[0]) or die "Could not open file '$ARGV[0]' $!\n";
while (<IN>) {
    chomp;
    $str .= $_;
}
close(IN);

# not sure if you were deliberately omitting the last two letters of sequence
# this looks at all the sequence
my $l_size = length($str) - 4;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $l_size; $i++) {
    $hash{ substr($str, $i, 5) }++;
}

# grep in a scalar context will count the values.
my $unique = grep { $_ == 1 } values %hash;

open OUT, ">output.txt" or die "Error opening output.txt: $!\n";
print OUT "Number of unique keys: ". $unique."\n";
print OUT Dumper(\%hash);
close OUT;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I parsed the entire file in seconds! I am fairly new to perl, I had no clue you could use grep in it, thanks for all the help :-)

Comment: No problem. It was quite fun to do!

Answer (score 1):

It might help to remove searching for information that you already have.

I don't see that `$j` depends upon `$i` so you're actually matching values to themselves. 
So you're getting bad counts as well. It works for 1, because 1 is the square of 1. 
But if for each five-character string you're counting strings that match, you're going 
to get the square of the actual number.

You would actually get better results if you did it this way:

```
# compute it once.
my $lim = length( $compare ) - 6;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < $lim; $i++ ){
    my $vs = substr( $compare, $i, 5 );

    # count each unique identity *once*
    # if it's in the table, we've already counted it.
    next if $hash{ $vs }; 

    $hash{ $vs }++; # we've found it, record it.

    for ( my $j = $i + 1; $j < $lim; $j++ ) {
        my $value = substr( $compare, $j, 5 );
        $hash{ $value }++ if $value eq $vs;
    }
}
```

However, it could be an improvement on this to do an `index` for your second loop
and let the c-level of perl do your matching for you.

```
   my $pos = $i;
   while ( $pos > -1 ) { 
       $pos = index( $compare, $vs, ++$pos );
       $hash{ $vs }++ if $pos > -1;
   }
```

Also, if you used index, and wanted to omit the last two characters--as you do, it might make sense to remove those from the characters you have to search:

```
substr( $compare, -2 ) = ''
```

But you could do *all* of this in one pass, as you loop through file. I believe the code
below is almost an equivalent.

```
my $last_4   = '';
my $last_row = '';
my $discard  = <$f1>;

# each row in the file after the first...
while ( $row = <$f1> ) { 
    chomp $row;
    $last_row = $row;
    $row      = $last_4 . $row;
    my $lim = length( $row ) - 5;
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < $lim; $i++ ) { 
        $hash{ substr( $row, $i, 5 ) }++;
    }
    # four is the maximum we can copy over to the new row and not 
    # double count a strand of characters at the end.
    $last_4 = substr( $row, -4 );
}

# I'm not sure what you're getting by omitting the last two characters of 
# the last row, but this would replicate it 
foreach my $bad_key ( map { substr( $last_row, $_ ) } ( -5, -6 )) { 
    --$hash{ $bad_key };
    delete $hash{ $bad_key } if $hash{ $bad_key } < 1;
}

# grep in a scalar context will count the values.
$unique = grep { $_ == 1 } values %hash;
```

Comment: Have you run this on sample data? It just gives me errors along the lines of `Argument "caggaccatttctgtatgtaagacaattctatccagcccgccacctctgg" isn't numeric in addition (+) at fasta.pl line 74, <DATA> line 65.`

Comment: Thanks, that sped it up a lot, I cannot believe that I missed the unnecessary for loop!

Comment: @anon are you trying to make a frequency table of how often sets of five nucleotides occur in the sequence? If so, you can speed it up even more than this.

Comment: That is what I am doing and I am open to any ideas for speed, I am currently testing the entire 7th chromosome and it is taking quite a while.

Comment: @anon OK, will post my code momentarily. What genome are you working on?

Comment: just a random one right now, but the file for it is 15mb of text, which is huge.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this more concise version of your code that uses a global regex match to find all the subsequences of five characters. It also reads the entire input file in one go, and removes the newlines afterwards.

The path to the input file is expected as a parameter on the command line, and the output is sent to `STDIN`, and can be redirected to a file on the command line, like this

```
perl subseq5.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

I've also used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) instead of `Data::Dumper` because I believe it to be vastly superior. However it is not a core module, and so you will probably need to install it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

use Data::Dump;

my $str = do { local $/; <>; };
$str =~ tr|$/||d;

my %dups;
++$dups{$1} while $str =~ /(?=(.{5}))/g;

my $unique = grep $_ == 1, values %dups;

print "Number of unique keys: $unique\n";

dd \%dups;
```